# array_values works in localhost, but returns nothing on server?

Tags: php, arrays, post

Update:
I found the cause. It was because the file only had carriage returns. After replacing them with CR+LF (`\r\n`), it works normally on the server.

Original post:

I just uploaded my site to my webhost and I noticed a strange issue regarding POST data. On localhost, everything works as it should, but on the server for some reason the POST data seems to vanish in the middle of processing?

The site submits data from a form to guestbookFormProcessor.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Add Guestbook Comment</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<?php
    var_dump($_POST); // This returns data OK on the server
    // Process POST data
    $unsafeFormData = array_values($_POST);
    var_dump($unsafeFormData); // This returns nothing on the server!
    // anything after this point will not appear on the page, not even echos
?>

</body>
</html>
```

But that outputs nothing at all on the server!

If I add an `echo 'Test';`, it appears on the page, but if I add it *after* the `$unsafeFormData = array_values($_POST);` then it does **not** appear?!

In fact, anything I add after that row, does not appear on the page. I also checked for any strange characters in the row, but it looks normal even to a hex editor. What could be wrong? It seems to be related to the array_values() function since this happens:

`var_dump($_POST);`
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Juha" ["antispam"]=> string(1) "4" ["antispamIndex"]=> string(1) "1" ["message"]=> string(4) "Test" ["submit"]=> string(4) "Send" }

`var_dump($unsafeFormData);`
(no output at all!)

Why would the POST data disappear after array_values()?

Thanks!

Comment: Do we really need to see all of your code to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I'll remove the unrelated things...

Comment: done a `view source` to see what does show up in the generated html? does the script's expected output simply STOP after your "Test" output? If so, then something's causing the script to crash.

Comment: The view source code is just the html, and nothing else (unless I echo something before the array_values() part. I also noticed nothing at all will output after that, even echo does not work.

Comment: Try creating a test array and use array_values on it and see of you get anything

Comment: The same thing happens. The first array_values returns the array data just fine, but adding a second one after the `$unsafeFormData` part will not appear at all, not even as null.

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause. The php file only had carriage returns, which apparently are not enough on the webhotel I am using. When I replaced all CRs with CR + NL (`\r\n`), everything works as it should.

Really strange, that!

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you use echo and foreach

```
$arr=(5,10,15,20);

foreach($arr as $value)

{
echo $value;
}
```

Comment: The problem is not related to creating/populating an array. The problem is that the array becomes empty during the processing.

Comment: i think because you are using post?and not storing them in a variable